# Reading json file returns string in python

Tags: python, json

I was working on a piece of code that reads a json file ever second or so in accordance with a pyqt5 graph. This was my code:

```
import csv
from getmac import get_mac_address as gma
import time

macaddr = gma()
mac_name = macaddr.replace(":", "")
weathersensor_id = "BME20"
rainsensor_id = "GCCG41"

def readJSONLatestAllMQTT():
    with open(f"{mac_name}_{weathersensor_id}.json", "r") as myfile:
        dataRead = json.load(myfile)
        time.sleep(0.01)
    return dataRead, True
```

When I went to access an element of the json file by doing something like `print(dataRead["Temperature"])`, I got an error message that said that dataRead was being output as a string, not a dict/json file like I intented. How would I go about turning dataRead into a dict instead of a string?

Here is the json file for some background:
`"{\"dateTime\": \"2021-06-18 07:47:33.710631\", \"Temperature\": 69.26586754195563, \"Pressure\": 346.63102628054014, \"Humidity\": 80.54066707990641, \"Altitude\": 125.3640651860123}"`

Comment: I don't think `PyQt5` is a relevant tag for your question. Instead of `json.loads`, try `ast.literal_eval(myfile)`  don't forget to `import ast`

Comment: My apologies, I accidentally left that in after editing my post. I will edit that right away.

Comment: Did you try using `ast` module that I mentioned in above comment?

Comment: You should use json.loads instead of json.load

Comment: Just FYI .   Those backslashes are what you use to escape double quotes in a json doc.  `{"stringvalue" : "abc\"d"}`.  Not sure who is doing what to your file, but it’s not “just Json” or at least not in the seemingly intended format.  Looks like maybe a double pass of `json.dumps`.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, all. Don'tAccept, I tried the ast module, but I couldn't find a way for it to constantly update a changing json file like I have.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having this problem because your json file is a string instead of a dictionary, I think it should be:

```
{"dateTime": "2021-06-18 07:47:33.710631", "Temperature": 69.26586754195563, "Pressure": 346.63102628054014, "Humidity": 80.54066707990641, "Altitude": 125.3640651860123}
```

instead of:

```
"{\"dateTime\": \"2021-06-18 07:47:33.710631\", \"Temperature\": 69.26586754195563, \"Pressure\": 346.63102628054014, \"Humidity\": 80.54066707990641, \"Altitude\": 125.3640651860123}"
```

Comment: I suggest you add some *code* to your answer.